# Piecewise functions Integration with symbol

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions, symbols, piecewise

I want to integrate one piecewise functions as following,

```
Assuming[ {t1 ∈ Reals && t1 > 0, t ∈ Reals && t > 0}, 
 Integrate[
  Piecewise[{{1,    x > 0    && x < t1}, 
            {-1,    x > t1   && x < 2*t1}, 
            {1,     x > 2*t1 && x < 3*t1},
            {1 - 1, x > 3*t1 && x < 4*t1},
            {0, True}}, x], {x, 0, t}]]
```

I have assumed t1>0 and why the output is as the picture shown[image]?

Comment: By the way...doesn't `t1>0` imply `t1 ∈ Reals`?

Comment: You can simplify the output by feeding it to `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Should the fourth piece of your piecewise function not be `-1` instead of `1-1`?

Comment: • Are you expecting an analytical (symbolic) answer or numerical? If numerical, you'll need to specify a numerical `t1`. • Did you intend to have the function undefined at the boundaries of each piece (ie. `x < t1` instead of `x <= t1`)?